# How do I resolve Cordova error code 72 when building iOS app?

Tags: visual-studio-cordova, cordova-ios

I am trying to build an iOS app within Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition. I'm using MacInCloud.com to build via remotebuild. I get the following error:

> 1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error : Remote build error from the build
>   server http://xxxxx.macincloud.com:3000/cordova - Build failed with
>   error Error code 72 for command: xcrun with args:
>   -sdk,iphoneos,PackageApplication,-v,/Users/userXXXXX/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/18897/cordovaApp/platforms/ios/build/device/MyApp.app,-o,/Users/userXXXXX/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/18897/cordovaApp/platforms/ios/build/device/MyApp.ipa

```
Using Cordova v6.3.1 
Tried various version of cordova-ios platforms ... 4.2.0 to 4.5.5. 
(Each comes with a slightly different variant of a build error)
Building using XCode v10.0 on Mac
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **remoteagent** from Visual Studio is just **too outdated** to be used with anything newer than Xcode 8.

I recommend creating a mirrored copy of your app and manually copying your www files to the Mac side when you are ready to deploy the app. Then build directly from the CLI in the Mac side and leave Visual Studio just to edit the contents of the www folder. This is explained in full detail here: [Build Cordova iOS app from Visual Studio for Windows](https://www.andreszsogon.com/build-cordova-ios-app-from-visual-studio-for-windows/)

Also, the newer your Xcode version, the newer your Cordova CLI version should be too. I'm now using Xcode 10.1 with Cordova 7.1.0 without problems.